# Why subquery returns <= Error Occurs

Tags: sql, t-sql

My sql query is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_PROJECT_CAT_D_LIST]    
@USER_ID BIGINT=NULL, @CAT_ID BIGINT=NULL, @DEPT_ID BIGINT=NULL    
AS    

IF(@CAT_ID > 0 )    
BEGIN    
  SELECT DETAIL_ID, DETAIL_CODE, SPEC_1, SPEC_2, SPEC_3, SPEC_4, CAT_ID    
  FROM PROJECT_CAT_DETAILS    
  WHERE CAT_ID=@CAT_ID      
END    
ELSE    
begin    

  IF(@DEPT_ID IS NULL)    
   SELECT @DEPT_ID=Dept_Id     
   FROM Employee_Master    
   WHERE Emp_Id=@USER_ID    


  CREATE TABLE #TEMP_DEPT ( DEPT_ID BIGINT, DEPT_NAME VARCHAR(100), PARENT_DEPT BIGINT )    
  INSERT INTO #TEMP_DEPT    
  ( DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, PARENT_DEPT )    
  EXEC [Dept_List] @DEPT_ID, 1,  @USER_ID    



  SELECT PCD.DETAIL_ID, PCD.DETAIL_CODE,ISNULL(SPEC_1,'')+ ' ' +ISNULL(SPEC_2,'') AS SPECSFI, PCD.SPEC_1, PCD.SPEC_2, PCD.SPEC_3, PCD.SPEC_4, PCD.CAT_ID,P.PROJECT_NAME,PC.CAT_NAME,    
  P.PROJECT_ID    
  FROM #TEMP_DEPT T, PROJECTS P, PROJECT_CAT PC, PROJECT_CAT_DETAILS PCD     
  WHERE T.DEPT_ID=P.DEPT_ID AND P.PROJECT_ID=PC.PROJECT_ID AND PC.CAT_ID=PCD.CAT_ID  AND Deleted !=1
  ORDER BY   PCD.DETAIL_ID DESC


  DROP TABLE #TEMP_DEPT    

end
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? What error do you get?

Comment: i have added a condition in sql query that is deleted!=0 then error comes

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your tables is hard to tell.. Maybe there is an alias missing for the DELETED field if it's present in more that one table..

Answer (score 1):

> I have added a condition in sql query that is deleted!=0 then error
>   comes

Based on your comment, it seems you are using a version prior to SQL Server 2005.

Comparison operator `!=` supports on [SQL Server 2005 and above](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx). Try changing it to `<>` operator.